# EC2 Cron - Not Loading External File

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I have built a program which loads values from an external file like so:

```
$terms = fopen('terms.csv','a+');
while($row = fgets($terms)) {
    $termarr[] = urlencode($row);
}
```

This works on localhost, as well as when launched on my EC2 server remotely through the command line. However, when I run this through a cron job (`*/5 * * * * ec2-user /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/html/loader.php`), the file is not loaded and I get errors later on in my script due to `$termarr` containing 0 elements.

Comment: Make sure you set your script to execute in the same directory as the file when run from cron; current working directory when run from cron is not necessarily the directory where the file you're executing is found

Comment: How would I find out the current working directory of cron? I have the file in the same directory as my script, but im assuming that is not the same directory the cron runs from

Comment: Don't even bother trying; just ensure that your script does a `chdir(realpath(__DIR__))`; to change the working directory to the directory where the script file is located, then it doesn't matter where cron executes from

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your cron :

```
*/5 * * * * ec2-user cd /var/www/html/ && /usr/bin/php -q loader.php
```

To make sure you are executing your script from /var/www/html

Last thing to checkout is the file's owner of your script, please be sure that ec2-user owns it, by chown it.

MrRhum.